# How do I remove multiple sesstionStorage values using keys?

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I want to remove multiple sessionStorage values using key/s, One way is I can remove it one by one like this `sessionStorage.removeItem('key1')` & `sessionStorage.removeItem('key2')` and so on.
So is there a way that I can remove multiple values like this easy `sessionStorage.removeItem('key1', 'key2')` or `sessionStorage.removeItem(['key1', 'key2'])`

Comment: `['key1', 'key3'].forEach(function(key) { sessionStorage.removeItem(key) };`

Answer (score 3):

You can only remove items one at a time ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem), [spec link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-storage-removeitem)). (Of course, you can use a list of keys and any looping construct.)

You could store your items as an array under a single key (using `JSON.stringify` when storing, `JSON.parse` when loading), and then you could remove the entire array (or replace it with an empty one) in one operation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such way, however there is something else you could do.

Instead of storing individual items you could store objects with multiple properties and then when you remove one you get rid of all its properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve what you are looking for is to overwrite the `removeItem` function of `sessionStorage`  with your own implementation.

Following example will show you how to wrap the `removeItem` with your own implementation which internally calls the original `removeItem` function.

```
function wrap(object, method, wrapper) {
    var fn = object[method];
    return object[method] = function() {
        return wrapper.apply(this, [fn.bind(this)].concat(
            Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
};

wrap(sessionStorage, "removeItem", function(orginalFn) {
    var originalParams = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);       
    for (var i = 0; i < originalParams[0].length; i++) {
        console.log('Removing Item- > ', originalParams[0][i])
        orginalFn.apply(null, [originalParams[0][i]]);
    }
});

sessionStorage.setItem("item1", "Item1 value");
sessionStorage.setItem("item2", "Item2 value");
sessionStorage.setItem("item3", "Item3 value");
sessionStorage.setItem("item4", "Item4 value");
//Call you custom removeItem method to remove both the key together.
sessionStorage.removeItem(["item1", "item2"]);
```

[Demo Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/IbKXRpFzsRfKjtGun2Bj?p=preview)